# Why are Google API manager credentials necessary? (Or are they?)

Tags: android, api, oauth-2.0, google-developers-console

I'm making an Android app that uses the Google Calendar API with a group of 3 other students, and we're struggling to understand the authentication process.

We expected to be able to be able to just include a Java library that calls the API and set our app to request calendar permissions, and then sign in to our personal Google accounts on our emulators and have the app be able to access our respective Calendars. We kept getting 403 (forbidden) errors, so obviously that didn't work.

So we tried to stumble through the confusing API documentation and copied some things from the Quickstart project. We managed to share the project with each other on the Google Developer Console and add OAuth credentials for each of our computers, and now it works for each of us, but we're still confused.

1. Why is this credential creation necessary?
2. How will the release process work? Obviously we don't want our users to have to generate SHA1 keys per-device to use our app from the Play Store.
3. Is there an easier way to do this? Do we even need the Developer Console?

These questions have likely already been answered, but I don't know enough about the process to know what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses OAuth 2.0 for user authentication. What it means is that whenever a third party app requires permission to access Google's data, user has to first approve that request.

Now, to provide authorization Google provides you credentials (key & secret),Using this key & secret Google generates Access key and Refresh key to the application.

Access Key: Key used to access data from Google server for limited time.
Refresh Key: Key used to fetch new access key when older one expires.

Now focusing on your questions.

Q: Why is this credential creation necessary?
A: Credentials to assure that only your app can access user's calender data.

Q: How will the release process work? Obviously we don't want our users to have to generate SHA1 keys per-device to use our app from the Play Store.
A: Google will generate access and refresh key.

Q: Is there an easier way to do this? Do we even need the Developer Console?
A: Trust me..once you figure it out,it is very easy and most importantly secure way. (Google does not allow authentication using password as default)

You can learn more from here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain whether/why we need a different credential for each debugging device, if we won't need a different one for each device after release?

Comment: No same credentials for all devices. And Google will provide different access & refersh keys for each and every accounts.